# ListPreferences not displaying

Tags: android

I have a listpreference that does not display the choices.
A box with the correct number of slots appears.  but the options are not in the slots.
I tried changing the theme.
Did not help.
I tried adding and removing the default value attribute.
That did not help.
I tried using the set Default Value method. 
That did not help.
I did this by the book and spent over a day on it.
Any ideas?

from the Options.class

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.options);
            //PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getApplicationContext(),R.xml.options,
            //false); 
    }
```

from the Preference xml file:

```
        <ListPreference
        android:title="@string/opt_cuisine_title"
        android:summary="@string/opt_cuisine_summary"
        android:defaultValue="Chinese"
        android:entries="@array/cuisine_preferences_array"
        android:entryValues="@array/cuisine_preferences"
        android:order="3"
        android:key="list" 
        />
```

from the resource/strings.xml file:

```
<string-array name="cuisine_preferences" >
    <item name="Israeli">Israeli</item>
    <item name="Thai">Thai</item>
    <item>Italian</item>
    <item>French</item>
    <item>Other</item>
</string-array>
<integer-array name="cuisine_preferences_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
</integer-array>
```

from the manifest:

```
 <activity
     android:name=".Options"
     android:label="@string/options_header"
 >
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `ListPreference` cannot read `<integer-array>`. Both `android:entries` and `android:entryValues` must be `<string-array>`. You can parse the strings into integers in the code, though.

Second, `android:entries` is what is shown on the screen, and `android:entryValues` is the value that is used internally.

Therefore,

```
<ListPreference
android:title="@string/opt_cuisine_title"
android:summary="@string/opt_cuisine_summary"
android:defaultValue="1"
android:entries="@array/cuisine_preferences"
android:entryValues="@array/cuisine_preferences_array"
android:order="3"
android:key="list" 
/>


<string-array name="cuisine_preferences" >
    <item>Israeli</item>
    <item>Thai</item>
    <item>Italian</item>
    <item>French</item>
    <item>Other</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="cuisine_preferences_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
</string-array>
```

EDIT: `android:defaultValue` should be one of `android:entryValues`. `<string-array>` items do not need `name` attribute.